# What determines length of stockfish 'pv'?

Tags: stockfish

Normally the length (sequence of moves) of what stockfish info prints out as 'pv' matches the search depth, but sometimes it doesn't. When determines its length?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this, but my understanding is that every now and then as Stockfish searches there will be a so-called "[fail high](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Fail-High)" or "[fail low](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Fail-Low)" which forces a re-search. Under these situations Stockfish might not know what the best PV is, but it does know the best move it has found is. That is when it outputs a 1-move PV.

See also [aspiration windows](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Aspiration_Windows) on the Chessprogramming Wiki.